# Require Cron syntax for MySQL maintenance

Tags: mysql, cron

I'm trying to set up a Cron job for deleting MySQL records where a date field is older than three weeks, but I can't figure out what the string is that goes in the box.
Here's a pic of the Cron management screen. Can anyone help please?
http://i46.tinypic.com/id4nsj.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the query you want to run, you can use the `-e` argument for mysql at the command line for your script.  So the "Command to Run" in your cron management tool would be:

```
mysql -u <username> -p<password> -h <name-of-mysql-server> <databasename> 
-e "<YOUR-QUERY-HERE>"
```

The general structure of a query to delete records older than a date is:

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [column] < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 WEEK);
```

Comment: Cheers for that - I'll give it a go tomorrow!